# While executing, application published on dev server still references files in the visual studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, filesystems, connection-string, publishing

I'm seeing something really strange so I don't really know whether it's the source of the problem.

I've published the application I was developing to the `dev server`. When I run the application, I get an error related to the connection to the database server.

The error is: `error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified`. I'm sure the **connection string** is fine. However, when I look at the stack trace, I see something like this"

```
MyApplication.MembershipRepository.GetRolesForUser(String UserName) 
    --> in C:\Users\<user name>\file path\MembershipRepository.vb:222
MyApplication.MasterPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
   --> in C:\Users\<user Name>\file path\MasterPage.Master.vb:5
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +109
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +165
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, ...) +4498
```

As you can see above, there are 2 lines that say `loading ... in C:\users\user name\...`

I don't just understand why the execution is loading or (at least) is referencing files from Visual Studio while I've already published the files a server located in **a different domain?**

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stackstrace information comes from the PDB files that are generated when you compile a program in debug mode...

You can read more about it here
[Program Database Files (C#, F#, and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903(v=vs.100).aspx)

Since this is your dev environment, there's nothing to worry about, you should however change the configuration to Release before publishing to a production environment.

Comment: By what you said, this is not the cause of the connection error?

Comment: No... the stacktrace is just additional information to tell you where the error occurred... your error is indicating that it couldn't contact some server...